# displaying widget in frontend and backend

Tags: magento, widget, frontend, backend

i'm starting with magento, and i'm creating a new module that uses widgets.
i have two question about displaying Widgets in frontend and backend.

In frontend from this  for example:

```
{{widget type="cms/widget_page_link" template="cms/widget/link/link_block.phtml" page_id="1"}}
```

to  a `<a href=""><a>`  code.

And in the backend, like under "/cms_page/edit/"  in the WYSIWYG mode, a small image allowing the edit by double click on it.

I hope that i've explained well the question.
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution for the first step :

```
 <?php
$filter = new Mage_Widget_Model_Template_Filter();
$_widget = $filter->filter('{{widget type="catalog/product_widget_link" anchor_text="Nokia" template="catalog/product/widget/link/link_block.phtml" id_path="product/16"}}');
echo $_widget;
?>
```